# Repositório central GIT + comunicação servidor externo

Tags: git, servidor, github, versionamento

Bom dia tenho uma dúvida, aqui na empresa em que trabalho pensamos em criar um servidor local compartilhado que será o repositório central e todos irão clonar e dar o `push`. Até ai tudo, bem ao invés de um `github` seria no servidor local mesmo que iriam ficar as alterações/novas versões, a questão é: Após dar o `push` para esse servidor local, como fazer para subir essas alterações para o site/sistema que está hospedado online?

É possível eu como desenvolvedor após dar o `push` pro repositório aqui local executar um comando e em seguida que se comunique com o site/sistema externo e suba as alterações? Não sei se fui clara.

Answer (score 5):

O processo de `executar um comando pra subir as alterações` se chama Deploy. Você pode fazer isso escrevendo seus próprios [`git hooks`](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Customizando-o-Git-Hooks-do-Git) ou integrando uma ferramenta externa.

Tem várias ferramentas que se integram a repositórios GIT pra fazer isso. Uma que eu gosto é o [DeployBot](https://deploybot.com/). Alguns serviços GIT mais avançados, tipo o [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/), também fazem isso automaticamente para setups mais simples, sem precisar de outra integração.

Normalmente você vai fazer uma integração e determinar regras tipo

> "quando um novo push for feito para o branch X automaticamente
>   copiar os arquivos alterados para o servidor Y depois rodar os comandos Z e W no servidor de destino".

Ferramentas como DeployBot se integram automaticamente a serviços conhecidos, como Gitlab, Github ou Bitbucket e oferecem um painel de controle onde você controla quais deploys foram feitos e pode desfazer ou refazer, entre outras ações.

A parte de especificar comandos para rodar no servidor é especialmente útil quando você está lidando com arquivos concatenados e minificados, muito comum em javascript. De forma que você só precise manter os arquivos-fonte versionados, reduzindo muito os conflitos de merge.

Comment: Opa, show de bola, vou pesquisar mais sobre o DeployBot e começar a fazer alguns testes aqui, obrigadão!